# URL Rewriting / base href / Firefox 3.x.x

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just finished our website for our company while using my frist time .htaccess file to rewrite URLS.
Everything works fine when it put the site online (Using a updated firefox version).

Now in our stores i had to install Firefox 3.5.17 becaus the internal system of our supplier only works in that version (strange enough but it is like it is..)

When testing our website on those computers it seems that my RewriteRules are not working, i even think that version of FireFox ignores the file..

So i have install a updated version of Firefox and that old version on my own computer and i have the same result.

I have use `<base href="/">`

And the content of my htaccessfile:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
```

The result should be:
website.com/../..
when i start to click on more links it becomes website/../../../.. and so on..

What am i doing wrong here? And how can i get this stuff to work.

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

I have change my base URL to the full domain. Like in described in the post below. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't your htaccess or your rules. It's not up to firefox to honor what's in the htaccess file, that's entirely a server side thing. Apache decides whether it should honor the contents of the file.

This is because that version of firefox doesn't honor the `<base>` tag without a FQDN. What you need to do is try including the hostname:

```
<base href="http://website.com/">
```

Or change **all** of your links to absolute URLs, so instead of having links like:

```
<a href=".../...">next link</a>
```

it needs to be:

```
<a href="/.../...">next link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you .. Thank you .. Thank you .. Thank you .. Thank you .. Thank you .. I have change my base to my full URL and it works. I was about to rewrite my full website again if i didn't found the solution wich you gave me. Updated my post with reference to your answer.